# How to combine contributions of individual type of cone cell sensitivity to get the human luminosity function?

Tags: visible-light, thermal-radiation

As shown in this figure from some computer vision book:

[image]

The data of three types of cone spectral responses is pulled down from:
http://cvrl.ioo.ucl.ac.uk/cones.htm

It is said that the Long, Medium and Short cone cells account for 65%, 33%, 2% of a total of 6 million. But I guess the response of individual cells may not be equal, so I looked up some reference and here in **Wald, George. "The receptors of human color vision." Science 145 (1964): 1007-1016.** I found the suggested ratio in this figure:

[image]

Unfortunately, I was unable to reproduce a perfect normalized luminosity function with this 2000 data and 1964 ratio...problem is that the combined function does not appear to be normalized to a maximum of 1.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** use your technique, but use scale factors of 0.690 for L, and 0.348 for M (instead of 0.542 and 0.575), and you will reproduce the luminosity function.

**Long answer:**

You're on the right track.  I tried to find 'official' scale values for the LMS curves online to combine into the [luminosity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminosity_function), but couldn't quickly get them.  You are correct that the three cone cell types don't respond with the same relative intensity.

Note that the various literature and committees have all agreed that the luminosity function V = L + M, and that the contribution of S is insignificant.  There is some debate around this, but the consensus seems to be to stick with L and M only.

So instead, I simply solved for the scale factors that give the best fit to the luminosity function (V).  These ended up being 0.690 for L, and 0.348 for M.  The data for V is from the same source as you got the LMS data: http://www.cvrl.org/lumindex.htm.  I solved using Excel's Solver and optimizing for the min difference between the two curves (V and L+M).

Previous scale factors (L = 0.542, M = 0.575):

[image]

Optimized scale factors (L = 0.690, M = 0.348):

[image]

Lastly, note that the [CIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Commission_on_Illumination) luminosity data is known to be not very accurate in the shorter (bluer) wavelengths.  The data in the link above for V is Judd-Vos modified 2° observer data.  If you have data for V which is based on the CIE 1924 standard for V, you will likely get a mismatch between V and L + M.

If you're interested in more details behind all this, the following papers are very relevant to this discussion.  They also offer some interesting history as to why the official CIE standard for visible photometry and colorimetry are not based on the science of cone spectral sensitivity (mostly because in 1931 the cone curves were not well established):
http://color.psych.upenn.edu/brainard/papers/Brainard_Stockman_Colorimetry.pdf
http://faculty.washington.edu/sbuck/545ColorClass/Boynton1996.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your effort. It seems a perfect match for your optimized ratio. Wonder if there is some place that mentions this as for an authoritative affirmation.

Comment: Section 5 of the Boynton paper I linked to discusses this a bit.  To quote:  "My view is that this is precisely how luminous efficiency should be defined, after the best weights of the L and M functions are determined for optimal agreement with flicker photometry and minimally distinct border mea- surements, which are known to agree reasonably well with one another."  In other words, the author is saying to do exactly what I did above.  The reference to 'flicker photometry' just translates to the data for V, because the original 1924 data comes from a technique called 'flicker photometry'.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. But that is simply not enough reading for me. I tried to read the Wiley classic book on colorimetry several months ago when I was in HK, but that ambition is stranded by a series of deadlines...What I hate most is the computer vision book does a terrible job in explaining things and made tons of mistakes. Yet the author, who is a IEEE fellow, does not even know that...